# How can I implement an abstraction layer using an adapter pattern that hides two classes behind a common interface?

Tags: java, interface, adapter, software-design, abstraction

The point is to create an abstraction that makes class1 and class2 look the same, not to create an adaptor that makes, for instance, class1 look like class2. I don’t want the BankController to ever directly use any classes in the com.bank1 and com.bank2 packages.I would like not to edit bank1 and bank2 class everything should get done in bankcontroller.java. The skeleton code is below.

Bankcontroller.java:

```
package com.pyyne.challenge.bank;

public class BankController {

}

public void printBalances() {
    System.out.println("Implement me to pull balance information from all available bank integrations and display them, one after the other.");
}

public void printTransactions() {
    System.out.println("Implement me to pull transactions from all available bank integrations and display them, one after the other.");
}
```

}
Bank1AccountSource.java:

```
package com.bank1.integration;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Bank1AccountSource {

public Double getAccountBalance(long accountId) {
    return 215.5d;
}
public String getAccountCurrency(long accountId) {
    return "USD";
}

public List<Bank1Transaction> getTransactions(long accountId, Date fromDate, Date toDate) {
    return Arrays.asList(
            new Bank1Transaction(100d, Bank1Transaction.TYPE_CREDIT, "Check deposit"),
            new Bank1Transaction(25.5d, Bank1Transaction.TYPE_DEBIT, "Debit card purchase"),
            new Bank1Transaction(225d, Bank1Transaction.TYPE_DEBIT, "Rent payment")
    );
}
```

}
Bank2AccountSource.java:

```
package com.bank2.integration;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Bank2AccountSource {
   public Bank2AccountBalance getBalance(long accountNum) {
      return new Bank2AccountBalance(512.5d, "USD");
}

public List<Bank2AccountTransaction> getTransactions(long accountNum, Date fromDate, Date toDate) {
    return Arrays.asList(
            new Bank2AccountTransaction(125d, Bank2AccountTransaction.TRANSACTION_TYPES.DEBIT, "Amazon.com"),
            new Bank2AccountTransaction(500d, Bank2AccountTransaction.TRANSACTION_TYPES.DEBIT, "Car insurance"),
            new Bank2AccountTransaction(800d, Bank2AccountTransaction.TRANSACTION_TYPES.CREDIT, "Salary")
    );
}
```

}

Bank1Transaction.java:

```
package com.bank1.integration;

import java.util.Date;

public class Bank1Transaction {

public static int TYPE_CREDIT = 1;
public static int TYPE_DEBIT = 2;

private double amount;
private int type;
private String text;

public Bank1Transaction(double amount, int type, String text) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.type = type;
    this.text = text;
}

public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
```

}

Bank2Transaction.java:

```
package com.bank2.integration;

public class Bank2AccountTransaction {

public static enum TRANSACTION_TYPES {
    DEBIT, CREDIT
}

private double amount;
private TRANSACTION_TYPES type;
private String text;

public Bank2AccountTransaction(double amount, TRANSACTION_TYPES type, String text) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.type = type;
    this.text = text;
}

public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public TRANSACTION_TYPES getType() {
    return type;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
```

}

Bank2AccountBalance:

```
package com.bank2.integration;

public class Bank2AccountBalance {

private double balance;
private String currency;

public Bank2AccountBalance(double balance, String currency) {
    this.balance = balance;
    this.currency = currency;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public String getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}
```

}

Comment: What part are you having difficulty with? The general approach would be to create a common interface definition, and then an implementation for each of the classes you're adapting that takes an instance of that class in the constructor and implements the common interface methods by translating them to calls on the underlying class.

Comment: Can you send me an example using this skeleton code?